# How can I display WPAlchemy post meta in my custom wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, image-upload

I am using the WPAlchemy class to create a meta box for my custom post type which includes image upload fields. The setup works and I can add image and save the images url for each post. I setup everything as shown here: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#installsetup

How do I now display the saved image meta url on my page? Ideally I would like to be able to display as an image on the page by adding the image's url to image src so it displays the image not the link. However I would be happy to just display the url on the page to start to make sure it's present. But I am really stuck knowing how to echo or print the info to the page. I have tried following some of their examples but nothing seems to be working and I sometimes get php errors saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function the_name() on a non-object in C:\
```

Any help appreciated. I thought it would be easier than it is, like the_meta() or something similar but it's not clear what to add to get the info showing up on page.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Best things to do is use:

```
global $custom_mb; 
$meta = $custom_mb->the_meta([ID_IS_OPTIONAL]);
```

`$meta` will be an array of all your stored values for the given post, loop through it as you normally would loop an array

Comment: Thank you. I will give your suggestion a try and see how I get on, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Farinspace, I am still not able to display the meta. My files are set up exactly like your website suggests. I have used the same code you provide, what meta key should I target to display this field and what code should I use? is the key imgurl?Thanks <?php $mb->the_field('imgurl'); ?>
    <?php $wpalchemy_media_access->setGroupName('nn')->setInsertButtonLabel('Insert Project Image'); ?>

   <p>
        <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getField(array('name' => $mb->get_the_name(), 'value' => $mb->get_the_value())); ?>
        <?php echo $wpalchemy_media_access->getButton(); ?>
    </p>